# getting an average of students graded test scores

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, user-input, do-while

Read in information for ALL students before doing any calculations or displaying any output. Verify
that the 3 exam scores are between 0-50 points and that the final is between 0-100 as they are entered.
Declared minimums and maximums as constant so that they can easily be updated, as needed. If invalid,
display an error message and allow the user to re-enter that invalid score. Once all student info is read
in, display each student’s name in the format LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME (all uppercase), the student’s
exam percentage (total of all exams plus final / total possible) to 1 decimal and the student’s final grade,
based on the following percentages:

> 90-100 A, 80-89.9 B, 70-79.9 C, 60-60.9 D, Below 60 F

[image: What the output is supposed to look like]

This is what i have typed out already but its giving me some errors and I'm not sure I'm assigning the values correctly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public class Proj4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
String again = "y";

int [] exams = new int[4];
int student = 1;

do
{

    String [] names = new String[student];
        System.out.print("PLease enter the name of student" + student );
        names[student-1] = s.nextLine();
        for ( int i = 1; i < exams.length; i++){
            if(i==4){
                System.out.print("Please enter score for Final Exam: ");
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter score for Exam" + i);
            exams[i] = s.nextInt(); 

                if((exams[1]<0||exams[1]>50)||(exams[2]<0||exams[2]>50)||(exams[3]<0||exams[3]>50)){
                    System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-50 only...");
                    System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                }
                else if(exams[4]<0||exams[4]>100){
                    System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-100 only...");
                    System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                }
        }
        System.out.println("do you wish to enter another?");
        again = s.nextLine();
    student++;
}while (again.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));
}
}
```

This is the error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Proj4.main(Proj4.java:32)

But its confusing because line 32 is just a } so i really don't know exactly what it means,
i know i probably need to reduce the length of one of the inputs for the arrays but I'm not sure which or if there's even more wrong than that.

EDIT:

Sorry here is my question, Would you guys help me figure out the problem and/or tell me if or what i am doing wrong to get the output required of me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array `exams` has 4 elements only but you try to access 5th element with index 4 here `exams[4]<0`. First index of array is 0 (not 1).

Comment: oh so instead of exams 1-4 it should be 0-3?

Comment: Probably you should change index `i` to 0 in `for (int i=0)` if you need to access first element in the loop.

Comment: okay i fixed that, but the code isn't printing out the line "Please enter score for Final Exam: " i reduced all the is by 1, set i=0 to start with, the if statement for it is if(i==3)...

Comment: any reason you can see that it might be doing that?

Comment: Check logic here as well `String [] names = new String[student];` You create fixed array with size student = 1;

Comment: would that array change as the value of student changes??

Comment: but if you need you can call `names = new String[student];` with new student value to create new array.

Comment: ohh okay, so if i put that line with my student++ line it will increase the array? or is that going to reset all assignments to it and just make it bigger?

Comment: You can create array (bigger one) again as I wrote above but it will not increase array which already created. You create array and assign to variable name again. If you don't need fixed size you can use ArrayList.

Comment: okay, but the thing is i'm going to need to print out the names entered into the array, if i just create a new array it will write over the first one and get rid of the already entered data correct?? would i just be able to create a big array of say 100 and just not fill all of it? sorry about asking you so many questions, you are being extremely helpful

Comment: oh okay, then forget my last comment i think i'll just make a big array. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work for you?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String again = "y";

        int[] exams = new int[4];
        int student = 1;

        do {

            String[] names = new String[student];
            System.out.print("PLease enter the name of student" + student);
            names[student - 1] = s.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + " i");
                if (i == 3) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter score for Final Exam: ");
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                    if (exams[3] < 0 || exams[3] > 100) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-100 only...");
                        System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                        exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Please enter score for Exam " + i);
                    exams[i] = s.nextInt();

                    if ((exams[i] < 0 || exams[i] > 50)) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid enter 0-50 only...");
                        System.out.print("Please re-enter score: ");
                        exams[i] = s.nextInt();
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("do you wish to enter another?");
                again = s.next();
                student++;
        } while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
```